# get smooth edges on rotated cube in unity 2d View

Tags: unity-game-engine

Edges of cube (white color) as not smooth when i rotate it. How can I havesmooth edges for the cube while it is rotated.

[image]

Comment: Maybe caused by low resolution? Try to go to your canvas and in `Canvas Scaler` change `Reference Pixels Per Unit` from `100` to e.g. `0.01`. However in general it might be caused by simply having a low display/camera resolution in general

Comment: @derHugo it's a 3d cube, not related to canvas, so canvas scaling won't do anything.

Answer (score -2):

You can have smooth edges on objects by increasing the resolution at which your game displays (this is done when the game is actually run, not in unity editor playmode itself), and by turning on [Anti-aliasing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Antialiasing.html)

Comment: The reason why it should have 30 chars at least is so you do not only post a link without any comment or explanation. This is no answer but maximum a comment.